# Output of JESS in Java

Tags: java, expert-system, jess

I want  to send a "fact" to a JESS file within java and get the results back. I basicly batch the JESS file and then send my data (structure in here) into the engine by .add(). I tried to get the JESS results, which should be a string, into a "Value".

```
Rete engine = new Rete();
engine.batch("file.clp");
Value = AAAnull;
try{
   engine.add(structure)
   AAA = engine.eval("(run)");
   } catch ...

System.out.println(AAA);
```

The result is always a number, although the result should be a string. I have worked it out in a simple java project and the AAA is returning the string, but here it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`(run)`](http://www.jessrules.com/jess/docs/71/functions.html#run) function returns the number of rules fired; that's the number you're seeing here.

The real results of running your program are the side effects it causes; getting the result in Java depends on what side effects you're expecting. That may mean anything from [collecting output printed to the screen](http://www.jessrules.com/jess/docs/71/library.html#routers), [finding newly created facts in working memory](http://www.jessrules.com/jess/docs/71/queries.html), or [having your Jess program call Java methods that effect the outside world](http://www.jessrules.com/jess/docs/71/java.html). Without seeing the contents of `file.clp` I can't say what you're expecting, but all of these things listed are covered in the Jess manual; the phrases above are links to the appropriate sections. I'm happy to answer any followup questions you might have.

Comment: thanks, I will go through the manual first and see what I can find out

Comment: I came to another problem. When I am trying to run the Rete engine in a actionlistnere, the engine is not running and I do not get any feedback from it. Is it because the engine is used inside a actionlistener?

Comment: No, that shouldn't be a problem. You can use the `(watch all)` command to see more of what Jess is doing and that might help.