# Jess router refer to TextField/TextArea in javaFx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, jess

I am looking to define a router in Java which take the Jess's printout content into **TextField/TextArea** of JavaFx GUI.

A similar question is asked here: [Jess printout contents print in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29871782/jess-printout-contents-print-in-java/29881933#29881933), but the problem is that I am using JavaFx which import `javafx.scene.control.TextArea` instead of `java.awt.TextArea` in Swing.

I've tried to extend the `TextAreaWriter` class and redefine the constractor to get `TextArea` object, but the problem still in `TextArea`'s *append* method.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to implement a suitable subclass of java.io.Writer. This object may then be used in a call to

```
rete.addOutputRouter( "t", writerToTextArea );
```

This is, of course, the same approach as outlined in the link; only you'll have to write a little more Java code yourself.

Comment: But, you must convert the content to String type, before you call appentText.

Comment: Which method in java.io.Writer inform me that: the router has been appended and you must update your textField.

Comment: Methods implementing append and write in all overloaded forms would have to do that.